# Is there a UITextField keyboard type that like a number pad but allows negative numbers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uikeyboardtype

I am setting the UIKeyboardType as UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad on my UITextFields. However, this only allows the user to enter positive integers. I need the user to be able to enter negative or positive integers. Is there a UIKeyboardType that is identical to  UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad but also includes the "-" (minus) symbol, and if not is there a way I can create this?

Thanks.

Comment: create your custom keyboard

Comment: Other option, add a (-)minus Button as a an inputAccessoryView. Or be happy with: UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation

Comment: @OnikIV How do add a minus button as an inputAccessoryView?

Comment: @user3210941 The code is in a answer

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Annoying as it is, there is no such system keyboard available. Other than creating a custom keyboard your best bet is `UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation`, and doing validation to enforce valid numeric entry.

Comment: UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad doesn't appear to have a minus button though. For neatness I would want it to be only the keys required though, so will have to look into creating a custom one.

Comment: Oops sorry, I actually meant UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation but copy/pasted the wrong one. Edited the answer.

Comment: In that case that is actually what I'm doing at the moment, but it looks a bit rubbish with all the punctuation and you can even switch to the alphabet on this keyboard.

Comment: I know, not pretty! I'd be curious to know what Apple's reasoning is. By the way, even UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation is problematic as it's iPhone-only and if you use it on iPad you get the same as UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation.

Comment: Does it?? I have only been testing on iPhone so far, that is bad. Thanks.

Comment: Gonna have to do validation regardless to handle a user pasting in text.

Answer (score 24):

Here's a version in Swift that has a +/- button and also a Clear and Done button for the numeric keyboard.

[numeric keyboard screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgGov.png)

```
extension UITextField {

func addNumericAccessory(addPlusMinus: Bool) {
    let numberToolbar = UIToolbar()
    numberToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default

    var accessories : [UIBarButtonItem] = []

    if addPlusMinus {
        accessories.append(UIBarButtonItem(title: "+/-", style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.plain, target: self, action: #selector(plusMinusPressed)))
        accessories.append(UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil))   //add padding after
    }

    accessories.append(UIBarButtonItem(title: "Clear", style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.plain, target: self, action: #selector(numberPadClear)))
    accessories.append(UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil))   //add padding space
    accessories.append(UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.plain, target: self, action: #selector(numberPadDone)))

    numberToolbar.items = accessories
    numberToolbar.sizeToFit()

    inputAccessoryView = numberToolbar
}

@objc func numberPadDone() {
    self.resignFirstResponder()
}

@objc func numberPadClear() {
    self.text = ""
}

@objc func plusMinusPressed() {
    guard let currentText = self.text else {
        return
    }
    if currentText.hasPrefix("-") {
        let offsetIndex = currentText.index(currentText.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)
        let substring = currentText[offsetIndex...]  //remove first character
        self.text = String(substring)
    }
    else {
        self.text = "-" + currentText
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Add a minus as accesoryView, you need have your textField as a Property, in this example this property is: myTextField;

You need to add, after create your myTextField this code, b.e. in viewDidLoad:

```
      UIView *inputAccesoryView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 40)];
// It´s good idea a view under the button in order to change the color...more custom option
inputAccesoryView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

UIButton *minusButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width-150)/2, 5, 150, 30)];
// configure the button here... you choose.
[minusButton setTitle:@"-" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[minusButton addTarget:self action:@selector(changeNumberSing) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[inputAccesoryView addSubview:minusButton];

self.myTextField.inputAccessoryView = inputAccesoryView;
```

And add the methods of this button in your viewController:

```
-(void)changeNumberSing
{
if ([self.myTextField.text hasPrefix:@"-"])
{
    self.myTextField.text = [self.myTextField.text substringFromIndex:1];
}else
{
    self.myTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"-%@",self.myTextField.text];
}
}
```

Comment: This works! Just had to set the button title colour to be black to see the text. This is above the keyboard though, is it possible to have it over the bottom left tile of the keyboard (which is empty space for the this keyboard type)?

Comment: No. You can draw above the keyboard. (b.e change the 'y' of the button, and the button will be above the keyboard). But it won't receive any event.

Comment: That's annoying. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: @AndyW Might be worth checking out how the "Set to black" thing interacts with the new dark mode

Comment: @Shayne thanks, however I actually ended up using the other answer in the end